# Make Phone Calls in Phonegap 4

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i am trying to make a call from my phonegap app. I was trying to do it by  tag, and i had add the CALL_PHONE permission in my manifest. Do i need to make anything else?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<a href="tel:+1-800-555-1234">call this number</a>
```

check this out

[Making a Phone Call from Within PhoneGap in Android and iOS](http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/02/making-a-phone-call-from-within-phonegap-in-android-and-ios/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. That's what i was trying to do, but i was not getting nothing. So, i do this instead of: window.open('tel:6164519', '_system', 'location=yes');  ... and it works fine. Thank you.